# Antiholomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-bundles

Let f be an antiholomorphic function in C. $z_0 \in C - C(0,1). $

Show that

$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint \frac {f(z)}{z-z_0} = \begin{cases}f(0) &\text{for } |z_0| < 1\\f(0) - f(\frac{1}{z_0}) &\text{for } |z_0|>1 \end{cases}$

Does anyone have any idea? I'm still thinking about it but don't know how to do it.

Comment: Is $C(0,1)$ the circle or the disk?

Comment: Define "antiholomorphic", what does "dla" mean, and what is the contour?

Comment: Antiholomorphic is a pretty standard term to be fair.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it. Antiholomorphic function : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiholomorphic_function

Comment: Are you sure for the case $|z_0| > 1$, the RHS should be $f(0) - f\left(\frac{1}{\bar{z}_0}\right)$.

Comment: @achillehui yes, this is the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(z)$ anti-holomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if
$f(z) = g(\bar{z})$ for some holomorphic function $g(z)$.
Notice on the unit circle $C(0,1)$, $\bar{z} = \frac{1}{z}$, we have

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C(0,1)} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} dz
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C(0,1)} \frac{g(\bar{z})}{z-z_0} dz
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C(0,1)} \frac{g\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)z}{z - z_0}\frac{dz}{z}$$
Notice under change of variable $\displaystyle\;w = \frac{1}{z}$,

- $\displaystyle\;\frac{dz}{z} = -\frac{dw}{w}$.
- $C(0,1)$ get mapped to $C(0,1)$ but the orientation of the contour get flipped.

The negative sign get cancelled out and we have

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C(0,1)} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} dz
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C(0,1)} \frac{g(w)}{1-z_0 w}\frac{dw}{w}\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C(0,1)} g(w)\left(\frac{1}{w} - \frac{1}{w - \frac{1}{z_0}}\right) dw\\
&= \begin{cases} 
g(0) - g(\frac{1}{z_0}), & |\frac{1}{z_0}| < 1\\
g(0), & |\frac{1}{z_0}| > 1
\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}
f(0), & |z_0| < 1\\
f(0) - f(\frac{1}{\bar{z}_0}), & |z_0| > 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
Please note that for the case $|z_0| > 1$ in last expression, 
it is $\displaystyle\;f\left(\frac{1}{\bar{z}_0}\right)$ 
instead of $\displaystyle\;f\left(\frac{1}{z_0}\right)$.